# Can't find storm logs directory in STORM_HOME

Tags: logging, apache-storm

When I install the storm 0.9.5 in linux, I can't find the logs directory as usual.The right directory is [image]

But actually I get the directory is [image]

As you seen, the logs directory disappears.
I wonder why the logs directory disappeared. And I start the storm as supervisor, the result is still so.

Answer (score 0):

I think the logs dir is created in somewhere else. Did you add $STORM_HOME as ./apche-storm-0.9.5 to your PATH and STORM HOME point to your current dir ?

Comment: Thanks, The problem is that jar dependency conflict.